# Is there any way in sql to resolve this scenario?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in database like this

```
CREATE TABLE assignments
(
    id                  uuid,
    owner_id            uuid      NOT NULL,     
);
```

Now I want to check in records , If `IDs` I am getting from request already exist or Not. If exist I will update owner_id  and If In request I Not getting a `ID` which already exist in table I have to delete that record.

(In short it's update mechanism In which I am getting multiple Id's to update in table and If there is already a record in database and In request aswell I will update in database , and If there is record in table but not in request I will delete that from database)

Comment: So you will not insert if an id is not in the db?

Comment: Have you considered `DELETE FROM assignments WHERE id NOT IN (<list_of_ids_from_request>)`?

Comment: For update, if you're asking how to update multiple rows with a single query, then that can be done with `UPDATE ... FROM (VALUES ....`.

Comment: @BurakSerdar  there are 3 cases , `1st`  , insert if there is no idea , `2nd` update if there is ID exist ,   `3rd` . Delete if ID is in database but not in request

Comment: @mkopriva so I have to run 2 queries , 1st delete all which are not in request . then update one by one ?

Comment: @Ninja yes two queries, one delete, one update. You don't need to run the update one-by-one, as I've already mentioned above you can use the update-from-values query to update multiple rows with a single call to the db.

Comment: You can simply delete all rows and reinsert what was received

Comment: @BurakSerdar  I can't delete all actually in future there would be a `status` field aswell . so Need to keep that aswell.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with a single Insert statement with the [ON Conflict](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-insert.html) clause. Your first task will be creating a PK (or UNIQUE) constraint on the table. Presumably that would be id.

```
alter table assignments 
      add constraint primary key (id);
```

Then insert your data, the 'on constraint' clause will update the owner_id for any existing id.

```
insert assignments(id, owner_id) 
       values ( <id>,<owner>) 
   on conflict (id) 
   do update 
         set owner_id = excluded.owner_id;
```